# The data node "Unreachable" cannot be restored to "healthy" after restart

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

I want to verify the status information of the node,start test as follow step:

1. start 3m2d cluster.
2. show datanode node,check the status;
3. kill one of the datanode ;
4. wait a litter minutes;
5. show datanode node,check the status; one of the datanode was 'Unreachable';
6. start the data node which was killed;
7. wait a litter minutes;
8. show datanode node,check the status; one of the datanode was 'Unreachable'; cannot recover healthy;

   Check the meta log:

```
2024-02-01T10:11:58.526608000Z  INFO meta::store::storage: METADATA WRITE(ver: 1046): /cluster_xxx/data_nodes_metrics/2001 :{"id":2001,"disk_free":23970435072,"disk_total":243107192832,"time":1706782318,"status":"Unreachable"}
```